# SignalR and switching servers and connection lost

Tags: signalr

SignalR is running on a certain Server with an open connnection.  If we need to bring up another server, then take the original down does SignalR automatically reconnect with the NEW server and start functioning like it was on the first?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and what we discovered was that SignalR does not automatically reconnect with the new server. Our solution to was to not use the generated proxy. We used an intermediary endpoint whose job it is to provide the current url to use. To connect to SignalR our flow calls the endpoint gets the result using that result we connect to that server for SignalR then when the SignalR connection closes or is lost we repeat the process again as if for the first time.

```
async function reconnect(connection){
   const signalRUrl = await request('<<our intermediary url>>');
   connection.hub.url = signalRUrl;
   connection.start();
}

var connection = $.hubConnection();
var hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('yourHub');
hubProxy.on('message',function(){});

await reconnect(connection);
connection.onClose(function () {
   reconnect(connection);
});
```

Comment: Why in the world is this not baked into SignalR? I don’t see why it doesn’t reconnect.  We use the same URL and everything.